# Matlab fvtool gives unexpected results

Tags: matlab, filter

I am trying to analyze an [exponential smoothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing) with transfer function:

[image]

Hence, for a gain=0.9, I analyze the filter as: `fvtool([0.1 0],[1 0.9])`

The zero/pole diagram has sense with a pole in z=-0.9 and a zero at z=0. However, the magnitude response does not look correct. It shows a high-pass filter, where the opposite is expected.

[image: Zero/Pole]
[image: Magnitude response]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a smoothing filter the denominator should be (1-az^-1). Not (1+az^-1). That is why you are seeing a high pass filter. The filter difference equation is of the form

y(t) = a * y(t-1) + (1-a) * x(t)

That will give a negative coefficient for the denominator.